# Count how many pixels are in a binary image

Tags: image, matlab, binary, pixel

I want to count the pixels on a binary image in a row. But, i need to count all layers i have and the pixels black in the layer on black and the pixels white in that layers white.

Sorry for my english ...
My code is:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('pass_p.png'));
level = graythresh(I);
bw = im2uint8(im2bw(I,level));

imshow(bw);
[Nx, Ny] = size(I);
cP = 0;
cB = 0;

%Vectores
B = zeros(1,9);
P = zeros(1,9);
for k = 2:Ny-1
    index = 1;
    if(bw(((Nx-1)/2),k ) == 0) %preto
        cP = cP + 1;
        if(bw(((Nx-1)/2)-1, (k-1)) == 255)
            B(1,index) = B(1,cB);
            cB = 0;
            index = index +1;  
        end
      end
      if(bw(((Nx-1)/2),k) == 255) %branco
          cB = cB + 1;
      if(bw(((Nx-1)/2)-1, (k-1)) == 0)
          P(1,index) = P(1,cP);
          cP = 0;
          index = index +1;
      end
     end
    end
```

My objective is detect a crosswalk. 
Thanks for your spend time :)

**EDIT**

This is an example image :

[image]

Comment: I really can't understand what you are after. Can you please try and explain yourself?

Comment: The objetive is to count how many layers I have black and white in a binary image (in my case, is a crosswalk), and within these layers counting the number of pixels that exist. you understand ?

Comment: Better to include a link to the image, so that we can run your code. What do you mean by layers?

Comment: So first, You have to detect the orientation of your crosswalk with maybe Hough Transform. After you will know if you have to count band in row or column. In this example image, you want to count by column

Comment: After that, you can just select one row or column and you have your mask of 0 and 1. Once it done, it an easy loop or vectorize function you can do.

Comment: The problem is that loop or vectorize, i'm not matlab pro, i'm a student, i have really difficult to make this loop. you have my code , can you tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: Look to my edit on my question. I can't do everything for you. But there a start. It work for 1 line. After just choose, how you can apply this to your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the question but there something to count number of black pixels in a bw image.

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('pass_p.png'));

bw = im2bw(I,graythresh(I));

figure;imshow(bw);

[Nx,Ny] = size(bw);
BlackPixelCount = zeros(Nx,1);
WhitePixelCount = zeros(Nx,1);

for it = 1:Nx
   blackPixel = find(bw(it,:) == 0);
   BlackPixelCount(it) = size(blackPixel,1);
   WhitePixelCount(it) = Ny -  BlackPixelCount(it);
end
```

**EDIT**

This is for a dumb example. So we expect to have only 1 row or column selected on the way of the crosswalk.

```
v = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0];
w =[ 1 v 1];

InvV = ~v;

w2 = [1 InvV 1];


runs_zeros = find(diff(w)==1)-find(diff(w)==-1); % lenghts of runs of 0's
runs_ones= find(diff(w2)==1)-find(diff(w2)==-1); % lenghts of runs of 1's

nbBlackBand = size(runs_zeros,2);
nbWhiteBand = size(runs_ones,2);
```

So after that you know you have the lenght of every band and the number of band of each sort. You can maybe take multiple line in your image and do the mean of that to get the mean of pixel per band. Otherwise you just have 1 sample.

Comment: Hi, 
you algorithm find me all the black pixel and white pixel, but what i really need is find a sequence of black pixel, and count how many are, in layers seperatly by white regions.

Comment: This is why I said I don't really understand the question. Can you provide a test image and maybe dumb example with small matrix ?

Comment: I will try... wait a litle :)

Comment: Can you check this link, exist a image, and you can understand what i need.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tH_Qo3-GvhdGN4OWxBSDJVd0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just post it in your question with an Edit. Because we need an autorization on google drive. And I'm not the only one that can answer to your question.

Comment: Today is a hard day ... i think that now you can see the picture

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tH_Qo3-GvhdGN4OWxBSDJVd0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you see the imagem now ?

Comment: Yes, I post an edit on your question, I don't have enought reputation to get it right way, I need review. But look at 2 comment I post on your question, that maybe can help you. I'm about to code you something fast.